# How to get data containing the Country, the phone country code and the mobile phone digits length?

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for data containing the name of the country, the phone country code, and the phone digits length (without the phone country code) like this

```
[{"name": "United States", "code": "+1", "length": 10},
  {"name": "China", "code": "+86", "length": 11}]
```

I don't need the landline number length, just the mobile number length. if a country can have multiple number lengths, like 7 and 8, then the dataset should have the max length, in this case, 8.

It would be great if I can get this data in JSON, but any format would do. I'm only finding this data on Wikipedias and such, with no reliable sources, and hard to work with, I need to copy and paste from webpages.

I need this data to validate input field phone numbers. I currently have 80 countries already, I'd like to have the complete list though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this website [globalcallforwarding.com/international-call-prefixes](https://www.globalcallforwarding.com/international-call-prefixes/) has the right data for you. It includes 242 Countries. To generate the JSON data from this, you can use this website https://tableconvert.com/html-to-json